# How to prepend a line to functions in a Python file

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, inspect

I'm working on a tool that needs to write content to the beginning of functions/methods in Python files.  I'm using Python's `inspect` to get the functions from a file. Given these objects, I'm using `inspect.getsourcelines(function_obj)` to get content of the function.  From there, my solution is to parse the function header and then write the necessary content after that.  My regex is:

`re.compile('def \w*\((\w|\s|,|=|\r|\*|\n|^\))*\):')`

This feels very brittle I'm positive it's missing edge cases.  Is there something more elegant/robust?  Would this be a good use case for the `ast` module

Comment: Yes, this would be an excellent use of the ast module.

Comment: Ok wonderful, I'll give it another shot.  Thanks for the guidance @MartijnPieters

Comment: @MartijnPieters you were super right.  Way easier than using the inspect module.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why my answer got deleted, but the two functions below are my solution to my problem of adding line statements to the beginning of functions in a Python file.

I'm using the term "routines" to mean any function or method in a file. Note that it doesn't seem to be easy to get the file from a AST node, so I store it with the AST node.

```
import ast

def get_routines_from_file(repo_file):
    '''
    Returns the methods and functions from the file
    '''
    routines = []

    with open(repo_file) as file:
        repo_file_content = file.read()
        repo_module = ast.parse(repo_file_content)
        for node in ast.walk(repo_module):
            if isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef):
                routines.append((node, repo_file))

    return routines


def prepend_statement(self, file, node, statement):
    '''
    Writes a statement to the beginning of the routine
    '''
    first_node = node.body[0]
    first_line_in_routine = first_node.lineno

    # you unfortunately can't used first_node.col_offset because comments
    # return -1 as their col_offset.
    column_offset = node.col_offset + 4
    indentation = ' ' * column_offset
    statement = indentation + statement + '\n'

    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        contents = f.readlines()

    contents.insert(first_line_in_routine - 1, statement)

    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(contents)
```